# Spring 2.5 dispatcher.xml configuration, "can not set bean property 'methodNameResolver'" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a legacy application. It has a main controller, JobController which is extended from org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController. This application was running previously (I don't know how) but currently during start-up I get an error related to methodNameResolver.

The error says "Invalid property 'methodNameResolver' of bean class [packageName.JobController]: Bean property 'methodNameResolver' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?"

My dispatcher.xml is like below

```
<bean class="packageName.JobController">

    <property name="methodNameResolver">

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                <prop key="/login.htm">hndLoginHTM</prop>               
                <prop key="/login.ajax">hndLoginAJAX</prop>
                <prop key="/logout.ajax">hndLogoutAJAX</prop>
                <prop key="/submit.data">hndSubmitData</prop>
                <prop key="/get.log">hndGetLog</prop>
                <prop key="/getJdbc.log">hndGetJdbcLog</prop>
                <prop key="/vtInsert.deneme">vtInsertTest</prop>            
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

 </bean>
```

When I replace "packageName.JobController" with "MultiActionController" then I do not get this error, however since MultiActionController is a spring class it does not include my methods (hndLoginHTM, hndLoginAJAX) so this causes a new error normally.

In summary, I thşnk that Spring does not understand that my controller is an instance of MultiActionController so it gives error to the property.

I already attempted to write the bean definition in various ways but nothing worked. Any help will be appreciated.

You may offer to upgrade the Spring version and use annotations.It is in our plans, but before doing that we need to make this version work and do some tests.

Regards,
Ferda

Comment: Can you show class definition of JobController ?

Comment: Can you paste the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry after this question I made some changes to the configuration. Later, after your  comments I tried to convert the conf to original state but I couldn't recreate the error :( Currently I am getting a new error which may be also related.

Comment: I get this two exceptions now. I opened new question for these errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189907/dispatcher-servlet-startup-error-configurablewebapplicationcontext-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this kind of configuration was very common in legacy java applications (my internet search result says so), I could find no way to fix this exception. I waited enough time I also could not get any suggestion to fix this.

So, I changed my plan and upgraded the Spring version and changed the method mappings to annotations. At this point I do not get this exception.