# Dispatcher servlet startup error- ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ID_PREFIX and existence of multiple context warning

Tags: java, spring, websphere, pom.xml

I get these two exceptions successively when I start my application on websphere application server.

1-

```
 Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [context] in application [MosipJobEar4]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:182)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet.init(ContextLoaderServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:345)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:604)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1201)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:785)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2220)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2225)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
```

2-

```
ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [dispatcher] in application [MosipJobEar4]: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ID_PREFIX
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:430)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
```

my web.xml is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <display-name>WEB_MosipJOB</display-name>
  <description>SGK MOSİP JOB</description>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB_MosipJOB</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <context-param>
  <param-name>CALISMA_ORTAMI</param-name>
    <param-value>TEST</param-value>
<!--     <param-value>PRODUCTION</param-value> -->
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>



  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/job/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/job/error/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>  
  <filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>tr.gov.sgk.mosip.job.filter.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Part of my pom file is like below:

```
    <spring.framework.spring.version>2.5.6</spring.framework.spring.version>
    <spring.framework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <!-- <spring.framework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>-->
    <!-- <spring.framework.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>-->


    <org.springframework.webflow.version>2.3.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.webflow.version>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-webflow -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I read that this error may be due to any depencency mismatch. I tried several versions but I couldn't fix it. I will be very happy if you can help me.
Regards,
Ferda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this is fixed, I was changing some configuration and also spring versions experimentally and

after deleting:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and updating the spring version to 4.8, I don't get this error.